# Como redondear numeros en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

es que tengo un codigo en Javascript pero necesito redondear ese numero y no se como.
Se que existe la funcionar match.round pero no me funciona, aquí va una parte del codigo.

```
$("#tamano").change(function() {
            var tamano = $(this).val()
            var data = tamano.split("/")
            var cant1 = document.getElementById("CANT1").value
            var material = document.getElementById("material").value
            var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value
            $("#PAP").val(data[0])
            $("#EXV").val(data[1])
            $("#AV").val(data[2])
            var q1 = (cant1/data[1]*data[2]/12*0.3048)
            $("#mat1", "#mat2", "#mat3", "#mat4").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)
               
        });
```

La parte que quiero redondear es `$("#mat1", "#mat2", "#mat3", "#mat4").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)`

Comment: Usa [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/round)

Comment: pero como lo uso en esa parte de codigo? es que no se especificamente en que parte se debe poner

Comment: Revisa la documentación, coloca toda la operación como primer parámetro de `round()` y especifica cuántos decimales quieres.

Comment: Dices que has probado con `match.round()` pero es `math.round()`

Answer (score 1):

Para redondear un número en Javascript se utiliza `toFixed()`. A este método se le pasa como parámetro la cantidad de decimales que queremos.

```js
let numero = 2000.430940943934439439349
console.log(numero.toFixed(3))
console.log(numero.toFixed(6))
```

Aunque si tambien quieres cambiar el formato al número (cambiando los puntos por comas por ejemplo) te recomiendo el método `.toLocaleString` que toma como parametro una región.

```js
let numero = 300934904343.98543984359435839853895443
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('es-AR'))
```

En tu ejemplo concreto sería

`Number(            $("#mat1", "#mat2", "#mat3", "#mat4").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad) ).toFixed(2)`
o
`Number(            $("#mat1", "#mat2", "#mat3", "#mat4").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad) ).toLocaleString('es-AR')`

(los valores pasados como parámetro son ejemplos)

Answer (score 0):

var numero = $("#mat1", "#mat2", "#mat3", "#mat4").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad);
console.log(Math.round(numero));